# Cannot change css attribute via javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is just a simple javascript code to change display or background or just to see if I can change the css attribute using javascript at all.

This is based on an example.

But for some reason, I cannot change the attribute using the js function I defined myself.

**HTML code**

```
<div id="question"> testting javascript</div>
<button onclick="close()">Close</button>
```

**JS code**

```
function close(){
    document.getElementById("question").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('question').style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
}
```

[The JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5oc62qbe/)

**The Full code**

```
<div id="question"> testting javascript</div>
<button onclick="close()">Close</button>
<script>
function close(){
    document.getElementById("question").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('question').style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Didi you use your function inside `$('document').ready(function(){});`?

Comment: @LuizHenrique that's jQuery, and OP isn't referencing jQuery anywhere.

Comment: uhhh no? because the example didn't use that

Comment: use a different name for `close` - because `window.close` is already a function - https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/5oc62qbe/12/

Comment: @JaromandaX changed close() to closed() but still not work

Comment: your fiddle loads javascript differently to mine (mine is in head, yours is on load) ... look at the console of your changed code you'll see you get an error when clicking the button

Comment: Why change the background color when display is set to none?

Comment: @Sukima nevermind that, just want to make sure that the function is called properly and working properly. also I just started learning JS so go easy on me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It *may* fail to work from 2 reasons:

1. JSFiddle wraps all JavaScript code within an anonymous function by default, so your `close()` function is **never** exposed to the main scope.
2. You chose the name `close` which is existing JavaScript method for closing the window: `window.close`.

The code below is working:

```js
window.closeQuestion = function() {
  document.getElementById("question").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('question').style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
};

/*/ This is a way of having a full control over your JavaScript functions and events: /*/
document.getElementById('closeBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  closeQuestion();
});
```

```css
#question {
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<div id="question"> testting javascript</div>

<!-- This is lame: -->
<button onclick="closeQuestion()">Close</button>

<!-- This is better: -->
<button id="closeBtn">Close (better)</button>
```

You should handle events in JavaScript anyway. Using `on*` attributes is *so last century*. See [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Comment: thanks. it is so last century for people who have experience. but I'm just starting to learn javascript that is why even the most basic confuses me. addEventListener and window.functionname <- I will look into this more

Comment: I would say it fails for both reasons you mentioned. If I change the name into something else, then I get an error log of a function that does not exist. That means before it did not find it, and assumed it is `window.close` function.

Comment: It's alright! Just keep that in mind while learning, so you can smoothly transition into writing a better code in the future! I recommend learning more about [JavaScript scopes](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Separation_of_behavior_from_markup). Good luck! ;-)

Comment: thanks. toddmoto site cannot be opened though

Comment: If the website doesn't work, there's also a great set of examples in the question [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript) here on StackOverflow. It can be a bit confusing at first, so I'll drop a little hint: Everything you define in a global scope ends up under a `window.` variable.